# Requests Python - Cross Origin API access denied even with headers, user-agent, and token. How do I get authroized?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, cross-domain, endpoint

Hello I'm new to dealing with servers and requests so bear with me,

I am trying to send get requests to an API hosted on a different server than the site itself (soldhistory.ca) so that I can get a JSON response of a list of property ids and then manually send individual requests to the API sever to get the details of each property. The later part works fine with my authorization token (and doesn't when I use a random string) so I know the issue isn't my authorization token but getting the initial json of property ids doesn't work.

I keep getting an 'Access Denied' - 403 message even when I send the headers, authorization token, and user-agent. When I send the wrong token, I get a different message that says 'Access Denied: Token not found or Expired'. When I send no token, it says 'Signature Required'. I think I am missing something trivial here. I have also noticed that when I login, the json response of that has an access token and another token that is different from the access token in it called 'token' which I think may have something to do with the problem I am experiencing but I have no idea what do with it. All in all, how do I get authorized to be able to send requests to the API server?

I have included a dummy account I have made with fake credentials in the code below if anyone wants to send requests. If you visit the site ,zoom out of the maps entirely and filter to show any price and only show sold properties, you will see there is data on roughly 450 000 past properties sold in Canada that I would like to get. My end goal is to get this data. If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

It is worth noting, I have also tried using selenium to initially go to the homepage and then transfer the cookies to the requests session but that didn't work either. I have also tried using selenium-requests with no luck either but maybe I did not implement those right.

Also, if you look at the XMLHttpRequests of the site you will that there is an initial request called properties that is made and then the subsequent get requests are generated from that json response. I am trying to get the JSON response for properties. It is a SEARCH method.

Code:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

s.get('https://www.soldhistory.ca')

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'SEARCH',
'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'access-token,access_token,content-type',
'Referer': 'https://www.soldhistory.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',
'Origin': 'https://www.soldhistory.ca',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

response = s.options('https://api.mapsearch.vps-private.net/properties', headers=headers)

headers2 = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Accept-Language': 'en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Origin': 'https://www.soldhistory.ca',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Referer': 'https://www.soldhistory.ca/',
}

data2 = '{"mail":"robbydummy123@gmail.com","pass":"helloworld"}'


response2 = s.post('https://www.soldhistory.ca/mapsearchapp/visitor/login', headers=headers2, data=data2, verify=True)

parsed = response2.json()
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=1, sort_keys=True))


accessToken = parsed['accessToken']



headers3 = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Accept-Language': 'en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
'access_token': accessToken,
'Access-Token': accessToken,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Content-Length': '317',
'Origin': 'https://www.soldhistory.ca',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Referer': 'https://www.soldhistory.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',
}

data3 = '{"query":{"coordinates":{"$geoWithin":{"$box":[[160.3305414532229,35.087235763335656],[2.6547602032228923,71.87799155489013]]}},"searchType":"residential","listingType":{"$in":["Sale","Sold","Rent"]}},"fields":["Latitude","Longitude","listingType","searchType","Price"],"sort":{"Price":1},"limit":20,"soldData":false}'

response3 = s.post('https://api.mapsearch.vps-private.net/properties', headers=headers3, data=data3)

parsed = response3.json()
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=1, sort_keys=True))
print(response3.status_code)
```

Comment: Why is `Selenium` tagged?

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried a solution with selenium but it didnt work so I thought I would tag it. It's my first question so I'm not sure what the etiquette is?

Comment: did you notice that there is also a key named 'token' in `response2`'s json? also, are there any instructions of how to use this api?

Comment: @tzadok hello, yes, I mentioned this in my original post but I'm not sure in what request header it goes in because it's doesnt belong in header3 based on what dev tools showed me. I did try to include it by chance but it still didnt work. Any idea where it could go? Also, I should have been clear, it's not a public api, I'm trying to send a request to an api enpoint on the site.